# Apache SOLR HttpTransportException

Tags: php, apache, exception, solr

Occasionally, I get exception mails from a customer's server telling me something with SOLR is going wrong:

```
Uncaught exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''0' Status: Communication Error' in C:\xxxxxxxxx\php\Apache\Solr\Service.php:338
```

or

```
Uncaught exception 'Apache_Solr_HttpTransportException' with message ''404' Status: Not Found' in C:\xxxxxxxxx\php\Apache\Solr\Service.php:338
```

Unfortunately, we don't have access to this machine. All we get are those Exception Mails triggered by their system.

Regardless of the fact it's a windows server, what could be the reason for these messages? I expect 404 to imply there are connection dropouts, but what about 0?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Spent my whole afternoon looking for a solution to the second exception! No luck yet! Good question!

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, you get '0' because no http operation have been performed since no connection have been established. 0 should the default value.